# Group MVC3 views into sub-folders under main 'action' folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

E.g. I have three payment controllers, each specific to a third party payment processor, so under my root Views folder, I have one folder for each of these controllers.  I would like to move these into Views\Payments\Processor1, Views\Payments\Processor2, etc. instead of the current Views\Processor1 etc.

I am not ready to implement areas yet, so I'm hoping there is some way I can tell MVC to also look in subfolders, or something like that.  Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write a custom view engine and [override the default view locations](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx):

```
public class MyRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyRazorViewEngine() : base()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Concat(new[] {
            "~/Views/Payments/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Payments/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"
        }).ToArray();

        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Concat(new[] {
            "~/Views/Payments/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Payments/{1}/{0}.vbhtml"
        }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then register it in `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyRazorViewEngine());
```

Comment: Ha! I think I'm going to add view location based on the Controller's immediate base class. Thanks.

Comment: oh my god life saver... just one note tho, the end folder you select for cshtml is truly blocked by mvc3 (which is good) but it means u have to create a sub folder for views only.. i did that.. i wanted a main root folder called DEV and inside of it i created a Views folder, then made the above class read ~/{1}/Views/{0} this way, DEV folder itself is still accessible for content, DEV/Views is blocked. Awesome

Comment: @darin-dimitrov How do you return the view within the controller?   `return View("Payments", collection);`  does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need for the views to be searched for?  You can specify which view to use in your View() call, complete with path.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, albeit very briefly, and it didn't work, so I just assumed it wan't on.  I'll try again, thanks.

Comment: You have to use the `~` to reference the root.  For example: `~/Views/Feature1/Home/Index.cshtml`

Comment: Aha, thanks.  I think that's my simplest short-term solution, although customizing the view engine has me drooling.