# MVC Routing: Creating sub folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my current project I have quite a lot of customer things going on, so I wanted to organise it accordingly.

I wanted my controllers to look like the following:

```
/Controllers/Customer/CustomerController.cs
/Controllers/Customer/CustomerResourceController.cs
/Controllers/Customer/CustomerDataFieldController.cs
```

And my views to look like this:

```
/Views/Customer/Customer/Index.cshtml
/Views/Customer/CustomerResource/Index.cshtml
/Views/Customer/CustomerDataField/Index.cshtml
```

I'm not sure to map this, I tried something amongst the lines of this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "customer_routing",
            "Customer/{controller}",
            new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Which gets my controllers correctly (I think), but how do I map my views correctly?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc or on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840941/group-mvc3-views-into-sub-folders-under-main-action-folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good approach for you is to use areas, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.98).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)