# Subfolder for MVC route not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller Foo and an action Bar.
The only route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "foo",
    url: "foo",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar" }
);
```

The URL **localhost://foo** works well;

If i change the route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "foo",
    url: "api/foo",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar" }
);
```

then **localhost://api/foo** doesn't work.

**WHY?**
I'm sure there's a question duplication somwhere, but i was unable to find it. Please, advice.

Comment: do you have any other route definition

Comment: @Shyju no. I specially created a brand new app and put only this route.

Comment: @Shyju at last i've found the problem. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fall.
In the **Application_Start** of global.asax there's a line:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
```

which overrides my "api" path.

Answer (score 0):

try `url: "~/api/foo"`

see this

[Controller in Sub Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178688/controller-in-sub-folder)

[MVC Routing: Creating sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875350/mvc-routing-creating-sub-folders)